# traverse array of objects and show image according to a type

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in a state in pinia, I get this array in my component. I am trying to show an image or others according to a value that is in the object, I make a function where I go through the array here and using switch I check the type, and return the image that corresponds to the type, I do this but I only get returns the first image if I use a for, if I do it with forEach it returns null, I try to save the value in the function because it is the one that I command to call to show the image, how can I do this so that according to a type I show a different image?

> Function where you tried to get the images

```
const imgSelect = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < obj.value.length; i++){
      switch(obj.value[i].type){
            case 'one':
              return new URL('../assets/images/image1.png', import.meta.url).href
              break;
            case 'two':
              return new URL('../assets/images/image2.png', import.meta.url).href
              break;
            case 'three':
              return new URL('../assets/images/image3.png', import.meta.url).href
              break;
            default:
              return null
              break;
      }
  }
}
```

> here I try to use the image, it is to show it on a map as a markup and show one image or another depending on the type

```
const imageMarker = imgSelect
```

Comment: You will have to use `Array.map`

Answer (score 0):

As commented

> You will have to use Array.map

You are only getting 1 image because you are using a `return` in `for` loop. So you return on 1st iteration and remaining iterations never gets evaluated

#### Sample:

```js
const getUrl = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'one':
      return new URL('../assets/images/image1.png',
        import.meta.url).href
      break;
    case 'two':
      return new URL('../assets/images/image2.png',
        import.meta.url).href
      break;
    case 'three':
      return new URL('../assets/images/image3.png',
        import.meta.url).href
      break;
    default:
      return null
      break;
  }
}

const imgSelect = () => {
  obj.value = obj.value.map(
    (item) => ({...item, url: getUrl(item.type)})
  )
}
```

If you have predefined list of images based on type, you can even create a predefined map and fetch from that. No need to create for every iteration.

```js
const URL_TYPE_MAP = {
  one: new URL('../assets/images/image1.png', import.meta.url).href,
  two: new URL('../assets/images/image2.png', import.meta.url).href,
  three: new URL('../assets/images/image3.png', import.meta.url).href,
}

const getUrl = (type) => {
  return URL_TYPE_MAP[type]
}
```